# Using TensorFlow pre-processing (tf.feature_column) in combination with scikit-learn model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

For my recent work I have to try different ML models on my given non-linear problem. I used TensorFlow and Keras to build a working version of logistic regression and of a neural network. Now I have to build an SVM classifier for the same problem. Since I could not find a working SVM estimator in TensorFlow, I was thinking of using scikit-learn instead. In my first two models I used tf.feature_column for pre-processing my data (bucketized_column, embedding_column, crossed_column etc.). Since this pre-processing is somehow complex and works pretty well, I was wondering if I can use the TensorFlow pre-processing in combination with scikit-learn.

Is this somehow possible? Or could I use scikit-learn somehow inside TensorFlow (similar like Keras), so I can also use TensorBoard for analysing my results?

Here an overview of the relevant parts in my code:

```
(feature_columns, train_ds, val_ds, test_ds) = preprocessing.getPreProcessedData(args.data, args.zip, args.batchSize)
```

In the model module I used this function call to get the pre-processed data. `feature_columns` is an array of the different types of the mappings of tf.feature_column. `train_ds` etc. are TensorFlow datasets.

Creating DenseFeature with the help of array `feature_columns`:

```
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, trainable=False)
```

Usage of pre-processing to build Keras model:

```
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        feature_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    ])
```

Fitting of the model:

```
    model.fit(train_ds,
              validation_data=val_ds,
              epochs=args.epoch,
              callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

Comment: Could you explain what is `feature_layer` in model you create? TensorFlow or Keras doesn't create how you create your data as long as they are in proper & valid format. So, assuming `train_ds` is in the desired format, it should be fine. Assuming, you are passing correct input shape while creating the model

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forgot to add this line in the first place (now I have edited the question). As you can see now, it is an object of the class ```tensorflow.python.feature_column.dense_features_v2.DenseFeatures```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve my problem.
I wrote a new function `(feature_columns, train, val, test) = preprocessing.getPreProcessedDataframes(args.data, args.zip, args.batchSize)` which returns panda dataframes instead of TensorFlow datasets.
Afterwards I used the `feature_layer` to apply the pre-processing on the dataframes which act as training input for the sklearn classifier.

Applying the pre-processing on the dataframes:

```
x_train = feature_layer(dict(train)).numpy()
x_test = feature_layer(dict(test)).numpy()
```

Training:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```